# Location Settings API NullPointerException - potential bug?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm using Google Play Service's new [Location Settings API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi.html) to display a dialog if there's any required location setting.

Inside an Activity containing a Fragment that itself contains a SupportMapFragment I use this code to check for the location settings:

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATES_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(LOCATION_SMALLES_DISPLACEMENT_METERS);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(GeofencingService.getGoogleApiClient(), builder.build()).setResultCallback(this);
```

Inside the ResultCallback I display the dialog like this:

```
@Override
public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
    switch (result.getStatus().getStatusCode()) {
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            try {
                result.getStatus().startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            break;

        ...
    }
}
```

It works nicely the first time I visit that Activity. But there's a strange problem if I visit other specific Activities (some don't even display any map) and then visit the first Activity any time after that, startResolutionForResult() crashes with this log:

```
03-24 11:52:37.485  20424-20424/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 20424
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.settings.LocationSettingsCheckerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates com.google.android.location.internal.n.b()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates com.google.android.location.internal.n.b()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.location.settings.LocationSettingsCheckerActivity.a(SourceFile:401)
        at com.google.android.location.settings.LocationSettingsCheckerActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:142)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

After that crash startResolutionForResult() then crashes every single time. The only workaround is to fully close the app and reopen it. Is that a bug? Did anyone else experience it? What can I do to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "other specific Activities"? Do you mean that you navigate to another app? Or some Activities in your own app? Is there anything special with those Activities which can trigger the problem?

Comment: @EdwardFox Well, a different [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in the same app. I can't find anything special about the ones that trigger it compared to the ones that don't.

Comment: Can you provide more context of your code? I can get exactly the same stacktrace as yours if I pass a negative request code into startResolutionForResult(). But I'm not quite sure it's exactly the same case as yours.

Comment: @EdwardFox I use exactly the same code as shown in the link I provided. The only difference is that I use only one location request instead of two. I added that part to my question. My request code is positive, by the way (25, to be exact).

Comment: Tested today, the bug completely disappeared ...